# Create SSH Tunnel is not working with proxy

Tags: macos, ssh, proxy, tunnel

I have access to a server using SSH using the command line:

`ssh my-server`

with this .ssh/config file:

```
Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

 Host my-server
  HostName 1.2.3.4
  User user
  ProxyJump some.proxy.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

However, if I want to create a tunnel with the server to access it via browser for example using:

`sudo ssh -L 80:my-server:80 my-server`

I get the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname my-server: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I would guess that using ssh this way ignores the proxy which is configured in the `.ssh/config` file. Is this correct or am I missing something else? Is there something else I can try?

Comment: I'm not sure of the details, but I don't think server names in the `-L` option get resolved via the ~.ssh/config file. What happens if you use `sudo ssh -L 80:127.0.01:80 my-server` instead?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I get the same `Could not resolve hostname my-server ...` error.

Comment: Does it work without the tunnel (`-L` part) at all? If not, I'd suspect some weird difference in how the hostname is spelled (like plain ASCII dash vs. fancy unicode dash) or weird formatting in the config file. Try printing the config file with `LC_ALL=C cat -vet ~/.ssh/config` and see if anything looks weird (other than the "$" at the end of each line -- `cat -e` does that to show where the line ends are). If the lines have a "^M" before the "$", you have a DOS/Windows formatted file, and that will absolutely cause trouble.

Comment: It's not working with the `-L` part but the `.ssh/config` file seems to be okay (no strange formatting or DOS line endings). Does the `ssh -L ...` commands even uses the `ProxyJump` entry in the `.ssh/config` file on default?

Comment: My understanding is that `-L` shouldn't affect the `ProxyJump` entry at all. It should make the SSH connection from client -> some.proxy.com -> 1.2.3.4, and then once that's set up *and* a connection's received on the local port 80, tell the remote end (1.2.3.4) to open a connection to my-server:80. And AIUI the resolution of "my-server" into an address to connect to is done via a normal hostname lookup on the remote computer (1.2.3.4), completely ignoring any config file(s).

Comment: D'Oh, I just realized the problem. When you use `sudo ssh`, it runs `ssh` as root, and looks for/uses the root account's ssh config file, not yours. It's the `sudo`, not `-L` that's causing the problem. Try adding `-F ~/.ssh/config` to the command and see if that fixes it. (Note: your shell will resolve the `~/` part to *your* home directory before running `sudo`, so this'll use your config file rather than root's.)

Comment: That makes sense. I'll try this tomorrow but I guess this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After chasing some red herrings in the comments, I'm pretty sure the actual problem has nothing to do with either `ProxyJump` or the `-L` tunnel; it's because of `sudo`. Running `sudo ssh` runs the `ssh` command under the root user ID, and hence it will look for .ssh/config under the root account's home directory instead of yours. And ~root/.ssh/config doesn't have an entry for `my-server` (if it even exists).

You should be able to fix this by adding `-F ~/.ssh/config` to the `ssh` options, to tell is to use *your* config file rather than root's. Note that the `~/` part will be expanded by the shell before it's passed to `sudo` (and then `ssh`) as a parameter, so the shell will expand it to *your* home directory rather than root's.

HOWEVER, I haven't tested this but I think the `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` entries in your config file will break, because they'll be resolved to root's ~/.ssh directory. You may need to give the explicit path to your home directory instead of the `~` shortcut. Another possibility would be to add `-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to the command line, so that again it'll be expanded by the shell running as you.

Also, you're likely to get warnings about unknown hosts etc because you'll be using root's ~/.ssh/known_hosts file.